# csh -> bash, autostart .bashrc PCBSD (FREEBSD)

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, bashrc, .profile

Hey Im stucked with this problem...

Im using PCBSD (freebsd) which has default csh shell, now I wanted to use bash as a default so I made

```
> chsh -s /bin/bash milo
```

now i have in passwd

```
> milo:*:1001:1001:milo:usr/home/milo:/bin/bash
```

everthing seems to be ok after reboot (bash default)

And now I need for my .bashrc to start automatically when login and it doesnt...

my bashrc is located by default in /compat/linux/etc/skel/.bashrc

bashrc obviously isnt starting automatically. I already tried source it to the ~/.profile,
usr/home/milo/.profile and .bash_profile and so on still nothing

I noticed (when Im in csh shell) that with .cshrc which is located in ~/cshrc (csh shell), I added aliases and after reboot everything was working!.

So there might be a issue with changing the shell vs autostarting files

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You should copy `/compat/linux/etc/skel/.bashrc` to your `$HOME` :

```
cp /compat/linux/etc/skel/.bashrc ~
editor ~/.bashrc || vi ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: THANKS! problem solved. My fail, I just navigaed to the wrong folder whole time and that was root folder not my user ~ folder.

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. If you think that the answer is well answerred, you can 'accept' it by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)